# Android action bar slide-out animation with RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, slide

I want to achieve the following effect:

I have a `RecyclerView` with

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="true"
```

and while scrolling, the actionbar should hide by sliding out of the screen when "hit" by a certain element of my RecyclerView. As if it is being pushed out of the screen by the RecyclerView element. (So simply `actionbar.hide()` won't do). If the scroll stops with the actionbar having been pushed halfway out, it should hide completely. The actionbar should reappear when scrolling down again.

All in all nearly the same effect of the action bar in the newsstand app.